# Orange canvas will not properly parse/open a file with a long header (column) line

Tags: orange

I have a tab delimited data set with 23 columns.  The header for this file names the 23 different features in the dataset.  The column names are...

> file  yval    size    err a-value b-value c-value d-value e-value f-value intensity   sat a-id    b-id    c-id    d-id    e-id    filter  training    drift   status  classification  second

This file does not open/parse properly in orange canvas.  The File widget shows this...

[image]

However if I remove any three characters from the columns row it works.  For example if I change second to sec like this...

> file  yval    size    err a-value b-value c-value d-value e-value f-value intensity   sat a-id    b-id    c-id    d-id    e-id    filter  training    drift   status  classification  **sec**

Or change f-value to f-va like this...

> file  yval    size    err a-value b-value c-value d-value e-value **f-va**    intensity   sat a-id    b-id    c-id    d-id    e-id    filter  training    drift   status  classification  second

Orange canvas properly parses the file and I get this...

[image]

This has to be a bug.  Why would orange canvas have a character limit on the header of the file?  It makes no sense.  Is there a fix for this?

EDIT:

Should have mentioned I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using Orange version 3.5.0.dev0+feea5ef

Comment: Can you share a couple of lines of your data?